# LINQ style Sample method

Tags: c#, linq

I Needed a method to randomly sample an IEnumerable collection without replacement. I'm using this for writing behavioral acceptance tests.

For example, in the test code, I write:
`GetElements("#SearchResults > li").Sample(3);`

Here's the how I implemented it:

I welcome any feedback or optimizations!

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  returns a random sample of the elements in an IEnumerable
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sample<T>(this IEnumerable<T> population, int sampleSize)
    {
        List<T> localPopulation = population.ToList();
        if (localPopulation.Count() < sample.size) return localPopulation;

        List<T> sample = new List<T>(sampleSize);

        Random random = new Random();
        while(sample.Count < sampleSize)
        {
            int i = random.Next(0, localPopulation.Count);
            sample.Add(localPopulation[i]);
            localPopulation.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        return sample;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `Random` generator a class-level member so you're not generating a new one with the default seed each time. Also, check your `population` for null:

```
/// <summary>
///  random number generator for the enumerable sampler.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Random random = new Random();

/// <summary>
///  returns a random sample of the elements in an IEnumerable
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> Sample<T>(this IEnumerable<T> population, int sampleSize)
{
    if (population == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    List<T> localPopulation = population.ToList();
    if (localPopulation.Count < sample.size) return localPopulation;

    List<T> sample = new List<T>(sampleSize);

    while(sample.Count < sampleSize)
    {
        int i = random.Next(0, localPopulation.Count);
        sample.Add(localPopulation[i]);
        localPopulation.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    return sample;
}
```

Comment: just a question but does .Count enumerate over all it's internals on each call or does it contain a local record count.  Just interested in the performance of including it in the while loop rather than storing to a local etc

Comment: `.Count()` does, but `.Count` does not. Subtle distinction there. `.Count` on a `List<T>` does not enumerate while `.Count()` is a LINQ extension on `IEnumerable<T>` which will enumerate.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer even `Count()` doesn't do that, if the source is `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @svick so it does type checking every time it's called and picks the best counting method available?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer, exactly, see [Jon Skeet's article about `Count()`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-7-count-and-longcount.aspx).

Comment: @svick cool, thanks for the info and link.

Comment: cheers thanks for that.  Subtle but good distinction to know!